# Jenkins displays help in mixed languages

Tags: jenkins, internationalization

Jenkins help entries are displayed in mixed languages.

I am using Jenkins with Google Chrome 43 under Win 7 Professional. Chrome is configured to be displayed in US English. The OS user interface is in German.

Jenkins user interface is displayed properly, i.e. in English. However some help items are displayed in German, some are in English, although they belong to the same section.[image: Help displayed in mixed languages]. In **Advanced Project Options** the help text for *Block build when **upstream** project is building* is displayed in German, whereas for *Block build when **downstream** project is building* is displayed n English.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's your browser's Accept-Language header set to?

Comment: Does this also impact you or everyone? If it impacts everyone make sure "locale" on the master returns "LANG=en_US.UTF-8".

Comment: My browser's (Chrome 43) Accept-Language header is set to English (US). 
Other developers are using German with either IE 9 or Firefox. The mentioned in my question help entries are displayed in German in their case. There are some English help entries, but they are originated from plugins, which may be not fully i18Ned.